# How to access nested object from Strapi using JS

Tags: javascript, graphql, strapi

I am trying to retrive some data from nested object.

This is the consle.log() result:

```
  console.log("bg data", data)
{
"pageLayouts": {
    "data": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "title": "a title",
                "layout": "home",
                "backgroundImage": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "attributes": {
                                "alternativeText": "bg image",
                                "url": "image url",
                                "__typename": "UploadFile"
                            },
                            "__typename": "UploadFileEntity"
                        }
                    ],
                    "__typename": "UploadFileRelationResponseCollection"
                },
                "__typename": "PageLayout"
            },
            "__typename": "PageLayoutEntity"
        }
    ],
    "__typename": "PageLayoutEntityResponseCollection"
}
```

}

[image: ![enter image description here]
What i need is the `URL`.

**What i tried:**

```
const backgroundImage = attributes?.pageLayouts?.data?.attributes.backgroundImage.data?.attributes?.url
```

plz if anyone knows what i am missing here.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Erhm, if `console.log(data);` outputs what you posted, then you should use `data`:

```js
const backgroundImage = data?.pageLayouts?.data?.attributes.backgroundImage.data?.attributes?.url
```

**Edit:** Missed the array parts (thanks Steve Hynding), but again, if `console.log(data);` outputs what you posted, use `data`:

```js
const backgroundImage = data?.pageLayouts?.data?.[0].attributes.backgroundImage.data?.[0].attributes?.url
```

Comment: Well i tried this but it give undefined.
    console.log("bg data", backgroundImage)

Comment: It's tje same thing, undefined

Comment: Np @SteveHynding. @Divad, without more in depth knowledge, my guess is that you are fetching the data and console.log'ing it inside the promise (`.then` or `async/await`), but trying to access `backgroundImage` outside, which you cannot do directly. Please provide more info regarding what you are trying and show more code.

Answer (score 2):

The `data` objects are Arrays but you are trying to read the properties as if it was just an object. You can still use unknown (`?.`) identifiers, you just need to do so on the array indices as such:

```
 const backgroundImage = attributes?.pageLayouts?.data?.[0]?.attributes.backgroundImage.data?.[0]?.attributes?.url
```

Note the addition of `?.[0]` to both `data` objects.

Comment: Hey thanks, it give undefined.
console:
    console.log("bg data", backgroundImage)